LLM chatbot calling a Discord bot
I created an LLM chatbot using RAG(Retrieval-Augemented Generation). This chatbot answers questions based on a specific context.
I want this chatbot to post questions related to users in a Discord channel. Basically, if the question is about a certain user that we know exists in the Discord channel, the LLM will answer: "I will contact the user on the Discord channel", then it will pass this information to a Discord bot that will post the actual question. It's important that the LLM keeps answering questions relating to the context. It's only when someone asks about a certain Discord user that it will call the Discord bot.
I have already created the Discord bot and it can connect and post question in a designated channel.
My question is this: how can I integrate the Discord bot to the LLM bot? I have added the name of the Discord users to the context, and I modified the Prompt to give instructions to the LLM that whenever the name of a user is mentioned in a question, then the LLM bot will somehow call the Discord bot.
This is the Prompt:
template = """<s>[INST]Answer the following question based only on the provided 
context.
If the user asks about a Discord user, give this answer: "I will contact the person on the Discord channel"
{context}

Your answer must be brief. Do not elaborate

{chat_history}
Human: {human_input} [/INST]
Chatbot:</s>"""

I am using Langchain, Mixtral for the model
